# Split string on basis of "/"

Tags: c#, string, date, split

I have a string:

```
string s = "1/09/2017 12:00:00 AM";
```

Output I want to show is **1/09/17**   (basically short date).

And if

```
string s ="30/09/2017 12:00:00 AM"
```

Output I want to show is **30/09/17**   (basically short date).

What I have tried is:

```
string[] values = s.Split('/');
string a = values[0]+"/"+values[1]+"/"+values[2].
```

I am confused how to get the 3rd part need help.

Comment: `s.Split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 6):

Use .NET built-in DateTime parsing.

For example:

```
string s = "1/09/2017 12:00:00 AM";
string format = "d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, null);
string output = parsedDateTime.ToString("d/MM/yy"); //output = 1/09/17
```

More info:

- [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`DateTime.ToString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This doesn't give the answer that the OP wants.

Comment: Op wants a two digit year as output

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the inbuilt date datatype. 
If that doesn't go with your requirement then I would suggest you to split the string based on the delimiter " "(blank space). Then pick the first part and proceed with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substring like this

```
string s = "30/09/2017 12:00:00 AM";

        string[] values = s.Split('/');
        string a = values[0] + "/" + values[1] + "/" + values[2].Substring(2,2);
```

Comment: `.Substring(2,3)` should be `.Substring(2,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("1/09/2017 12:00:00 AM", "d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d/MM/yy"));
```

Convert your date string to `DateTime` and then use `ToString` overloaded method method with parameter `Format` Please find [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WHHKRz)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Paolo's anwer

```
            string s = "1/09/2017 12:00:00 AM";
            string format = "d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
            DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, null);
            string output = parsedDateTime.ToString("d/MM/yy");
            string ss = output.Replace("-","/");
            Console.Write(ss); //output is 1/09/17
```

This will exactly return the exact expected output